# Dropdown menu is out of the screen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to add a dropdown menu to my navbar but the menu is always out of the page.

Here is my code :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">PEL</a>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle mr-3"
      data-toggle="dropdown"
      aria-haspopup="true"
      aria-expanded="false">${pseudo}</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
      <button
        class="dropdown-item dropdown-menu-right"
        type="button">Action</button>
      <button
        class="dropdown-item dropdown-menu-right"
        type="button">Another action</button>
      <button
        class="dropdown-item dropdown-menu-right"
        type="button">Something else here</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Dropdown works good but it is always out of the right side of my screen...

[image]
[image]

A little space is created by my dropdown menu on the right side of the page.

Answer (score 0):

According to the v4.0 doc :

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#menu-alignment

> Heads up! Dropdowns are positioned thanks to Popper.js (**except when they are contained in a navbar**).

Two options :

1. Upgrade your bootstrap version. It's working fine with v4.6
2. Use custom classes instead of bootstrap navbar

[EDIT 1] Here is a working example with bootstrap v4.6. Also i have removed the `mr-3` class for better rendering.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">


<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">PEL</a>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
      data-toggle="dropdown"
      aria-haspopup="true"
      aria-expanded="false">${pseudo}</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
      <button
        class="dropdown-item"
        type="button">Action</button>
      <button
        class="dropdown-item"
        type="button">Another action</button>
      <button
        class="dropdown-item"
        type="button">Something else here</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I updated my bootstrap version and nothing better, might have to use custom classes...

Comment: @LePainDemi Try the updated answer, it should work.